# PowerShell cmdlet get-service returns different results remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

If I run the following command remotely from a server it returns a list of 37 services.

```
get-service -computername <computer name>
```

If I connect to the remote host and run the same command through a remote session it returns a list of 161 services.

```
new-pssession <computer-mame>
enter-pssession <session id>
get-service
```

can anybody point to me to an explanation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your result. Try the following snippets:

```
$ComputerName = 'ComputerName'

$ServiceList = Get-Service -ComputerName $ComputerName
$ServiceList.count

$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
    $ServiceList = Get-Service
    $ServiceList.count
}
```

Comment: strangely neither can I now and yet I could reproduce it on every attempt yesterday afternoon and again this morning.  Both snippets (and the raw command I used) return the same count. How bizarre.

Comment: I cant mark both answers correct albeit both answer would work. I have marked the one that is clearer and gives more context, no offence meant to @neil

Comment: So it seems to have been an issue with your computer or with your console session and not with the code. Sometimes the good old "have you tried to close it and open it again?" helps.  ;-)

Comment: I initially ran the command in two different terminals on two different machines in an attempt to remove that issue. A colleague also tested it with me on her workstation. I cant explain the behaviour at all, I ran the successful ones in the same terminal and session I had run the failed ones. The ONLY difference was time elapsed and the fact I had started and ended the remote session connection between the two. If I get to the bottom of it I'll update with the findings.

Answer (score 0):

Try Invoking the command on the remote computer and storing the results in a Variable

```
$remoteCommputer = "RemoteComputerName" 
$GetServiceData = (invoke-command -ComputerName $remoteCommputer -ScriptBlock { get-service })
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.